# Similar system call of unshare (Linux) on FreeBSD

Tags: unix, freebsd, glibc, file-descriptor, libc

I am using unshare(CLONE_FILES) on Linux to separate FD tables. Is there any similar system calls on FreeBSD?

(Edit: mentioned in comment, it seems rfork_thread won’t work in this case) I have tried `rfork_thread(RFFDG|RFTHREAD, malloc(8000000), &myRoutine, arg)`, but it returns 0(no thread created)? As stated in the manual, `rfork_thread` has been deprecated in favor of `pthread_create`, and I didn’t find sample code that uses this system call.

Thanks in advance for providing any clues on how to achieve this on FreeBSD.

Comment: Judging from the man page, you can't use `RFFDG` and `RFTHREAD` simultaneously.

Comment: @arrowd Ah, thank you arrowd. I was not careful. Then it seems rfork_thread is not the right way to go.